# pros and cons of Territory management

Tags: sharing, territory-management

pros and cons of Territory management.
can any one give the clear example, how the role sharing is effected to territory sharing

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, sharing is set to private, meaning roles are not used for sharing when Territories are enabled. This is best explained in [4 steps to deciding if territory management is right for you](https://help.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=01530000001x38AAAQ).

Here's an example table from the document where sharing has been set to private.

[image: Role Hierarchy and Territory Hierarchy]